# How to update Oracle APEX DB table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want the ability for my application to switch between custom authentication and an LDAP string. essentially I want this to be a setting that can be updated on an admin page.  I know that this is just a matter of updating the APEX_APPLICATION_AUTH table and setting the column IS_CURRENT_AUTHENTICATION appropriately to 'N' and 'Y'.

obviously we cannot use a simple update command to achieve this.

Is there a function that will allow for such a change to take place, or is there another way around a user being able to update between LDAP and a customer function?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would only use the built-in APEX LDAP authentication scheme if I knew that we would *only* be using LDAP. If you want to use LDAP for authentication *some* of the time, I think you're best off implementing a custom authentication scheme. Then you can have a flag in your own table that you check; if it's enabled, authenticate the username/password using DBMS_LDAP, and if it's disabled, do some other kind of local authentication.

This approach also makes it easy to enable LDAP authentication on a *per-user* basis, where you can check your user table to see if a user has an "ldap_enabled" flag and choose which type of authentication you want to use for them based on that.

[This article describes how to implement LDAP authentication](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-application-express-apex-ldap-authentication) as a custom authentication scheme.